# Regular Expression pattern for alphanumeric username

Tags: html, regex, forms, validation, input

I want to enter the user username as **alphanumeric string**.

- Both letters and numbers should be in string.
- String should start with with alphabets and end with numbers.
- It can contain only underscores as special charachter(optional).

My code

```html
 <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Choose Username" 
  pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+${7,25}" autocomplete="off" required>
```

Comment: Use `pattern="(?=\D*\d)(?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])[a-zA-Z]\w{5,23}\d"`

Comment: Please be more precise and provide a few examples of valid and invalid usernames. For example, is `"abc123def456"` valid, or can no letter be preceded by a digit? Also, you say nothing in your question about the need for `{7,25}`, though I presume that refers to the required length of the username.

Comment: If the string should start with alphabets, and end with a digit, then "in theory" this requirement `both letters and numbers should be in string` is already fulfilled using `pattern="[a-zA-Z]\w{5,23}\d"` Or is that not what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You need a positive lookahead

https://regex101.com/r/280p8a/1

`^(?=\w{7,25}$)[A-Za-z]\w+\d$)`

```
Positive Lookahead (?=^.{7,25}$)
Assert that the Regex below matches
^ asserts position at start of a line
\w matches any word character ([a-zA-Z0-9_])
{7,25} matches the previous token between 7 and 25 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```

Comment: The string can only contain word characters, you could put the anchor at the start outside of the lookahead and then in the assertion use `\w` instead of `.` to fail it earlier if it matches a non word character. You can also omit the capture group for the match. `^(?=\w{7,25}$)[A-Za-z]\w+\d$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Great improvement